# Google Authentication Exception- No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Cookies

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, google-authentication

I am working with google authentication in .net core but when redirecting from google it showing me exception- InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Cookies

Here is my Setting for startup.cs

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied"),
        });

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            DisplayName = "Google",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",
            ClientId = "ClientId ",
            ClientSecret = "ClientSecret ",
            Scope = { "email", "openid" },
            CallbackPath = "/home",
        });
```

Please suggest me where I am wrong

[image: Error Page]

Answer (score 0):

You may register the default `CookieAuthenticationHandler` handler provided by ASP.NET Core by using `AddCookieAuthentication` extension method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
```

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddCookieAuthentication();
       ...
   }

**Update**:

There was a [breaking change](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/232) in Authentication Middleware. Now ASP.NET Core has only one `AddAuthentication()` extension method and all configuration goes throw corresponding `UseXXXAuthentication` extension method. For simple example look into [Security repo samples](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/samples/CookieSample/Startup.cs):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     ...
     app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
     {
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true
     });
}
```

Look into [authentication-cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) section in documentation for available options

Comment: AddCookieAuthentication is not a method of the IServiceCollection object. I confirmed this namespace is referenced, and still get this exception.