# Google Authentication- .Net core - The oauth state was missing or invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-authentication

[image]I am trying to use google authentication in .net core but its giving me error - The oauth state was missing or invalid.

Please suggest what i am doing wrong

Comment: Give more information about when the problem occurs and eventually some code along with it.

Comment: Please see my setting  for app startup- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607514/google-authentication-exception-no-authentication-handler-is-configured-to-hand

Comment: app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance",
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied"),
        });

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            DisplayName = "Google",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",
            ClientId = "ClientId ",
            ClientSecret = "ClientSecret ",
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
//For google client....
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { BooksService.Scope.Books },
                "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"));
        }

// Create the service.
        var service = new BooksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Books API Sample",
            });
  var bookshelves = await service.Mylibrary.Bookshelves.List().ExecuteAsync();
        ...
    }

 Thats the example of how you can create google client and service to make google authentication
```

Comment: If you have any problem #amethianil.. comment me

Comment: I have created Google authentication part please check here my startup.cs class setting- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607514/google-authentication-exception-no-authentication-handler-is-configured-to-hand
When its redirecting from google then its showing this error-The oauth state was missing or invalid 
I have implemented its in .net working fine but in .net core not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the problem is that you incorretly set the `googleOptions.CallbackPath`. 
Try this answer. It helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61950614/9547346